# Cleaning data in dataframe python. I need to convert the price from str to decimal with zero respective to the str

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I want to convert the price columns into int by replacing the 'Cr' and 'lac' with respective zeros (see [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system))

[image]

Comment: Your image is not visible. Paste long lasting links.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to set up a function that does the conversion. Then you use apply() to run it on all the prices. Just make sure you have some sort of error checking in case prices come in in an unexpected format.

```
def price_fl(price_str):    
        conv = {'Cr':10000000, 'Lac':100000}
        s = price_str.split()
        return float(s[0]) * conv.get(s[1])

df['prices'] = df['prices'].apply(price_fl)
```